# how do I reset the default photo image size for sharing

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, photos, gallery

how do I reset the default photo image size for sharing, it is set too large and I can't find where to reset to a smaller image since I said not to ask each time

Comment: Sharing via what? MMS?

Answer (score 1):

Go to settings -> apps -> gallery -> clear data